# Unable to get a single file not found output from script in Python

Tags: python

So I have a small database file written by an application on Linux and Windows.  When the application runs, it writes the database file and data, but if it hasn't ran yet, no file or data.  The script I have will run and gather the filenames from the database.  Here is the issue:  When the file if is not there, it will output that the database.db doesn't exist over and over for all files it does find and when it does exist, it will output the same thing and the requested data.  I since the directory structure is different for the OS's, I cannot hard code the path directly for the database file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def database():
    with open ('Analysis.txt', 'w') as f: f.write (' \nDatabase Analysis: \n\n')

    import os, sqlite3
    from os import path
    import sqlite3 as lite

    PATH = "./"

    for path, dirs, files, in os.walk(PATH):
        for filename in files:
            fullpath =os.path.join(path, filename)
            if filename == 'database.db':
                conn = sqlite3.connect(fullpath)
                output = open("Analysis.txt", "a")

                cursor = conn.execute("select filename from history desc limit 100;")
                for row in cursor:
                    output.write(str(row) + "\n")
                conn.close()

            elif not os.path.isfile('database.db'):
                with open('Analysis.txt', 'a') as f1:
                    f1.write("database.db does not exist.")
                    f1.close()
database()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modification should do the job:

#!/usr/bin/python

```
def database():
    with open ('Analysis.txt', 'w') as f: f.write (' \nDatabase Analysis: \n\n')

    import os, sqlite3
    from os import path
    import sqlite3 as lite

    PATH = "./"
    exist = False

    for path, dirs, files, in os.walk(PATH):
        for filename in files:
            fullpath =os.path.join(path, filename)
            if filename == 'database.db':
                conn = sqlite3.connect(fullpath)
                output = open("Analysis.txt", "a")

                cursor = conn.execute("select filename from history desc limit 100;")
                for row in cursor:
                    output.write(str(row) + "\n")
                conn.close()
                exist = True
                break
            else:
                continue
    if not exist:
            with open('Analysis.txt', 'a') as f1:
                f1.write("database.db does not exist.")
                f1.close()
database()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I assume you want to find a file called 'database.db' under the current directory, then execute some code on that file, and write the output to a file.

I would tackle this problem by dividing it into sub problems( find the file, execute the code, output to a file )

**find the file**

```
def find_file_recursive(top, name_pattern):
    """
    walks over all the files under the current directory, 
    moving down the directory structure as needed.

    If the filename matches the name_pattern, yield the path for the file
    """
    filepat = re.compile(name_pattern)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for file in files:
            if filepat.match(file):
                yield os.path.join(path, file)
```

**execute the code on the database:**

```
def write_rows_to_file(database, output_file):
    """
    opens a sqlite database, reads the filename from history 
    table and writes that to the output_file
    """
    with sqlite3.connect(fullpath) as conn:
        for row in conn.execute("select filename from history desc limit 100;"):
            output.write(row[0] + "\n")
```

By passing in the file, you can possible reuse this code later a bit easier.

**running and output to the file**

```
import os
import re
import sqlite3

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for database in find_file_recursive('.', '^database.db$'):
        write_rows_to_file(database, out_file)
```

Note that you do not need the `close` method, both on the file and on the connection, as this is done by the `with` construct.

Comment: I definitely like what you did here as you made it very organized.  I will keep this in mind if I branch this out.